Почему появляется ошибка error: 'No working liteservers with ls_index=None, archival=None'?
Я пытаюсь написать код, который будет пересылать TON токены, он работает, но не всегда, время от времени выскакиват ошибка:
error: 'No working liteservers with ls_index=None, archival=None'
Если бы эта ошибка была вызвана тех перерывом на стороне сервера TON, но ошибка появляется для такого варианта
Вот мой код:
async sendTon(amount: number, address: string) {
    const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC_WALLET ? process.env.MNEMONIC_WALLET : '';
    const key = await mnemonicToWalletKey(mnemonic.split(' '));
    amount = 0.01;
    const wallet = WalletContractV5R1.create({
      publicKey: key.publicKey,
      workchain: 0,
    });

    const endpoint = await getHttpEndpoint({
      network: 'testnet',
    });
    const client = new TonClient({
      endpoint,
      timeout: 100_000,
      apiKey: 'он здесь есть и он правильный, я проверил',
    });

    const isDeployed = await client.isContractDeployed(wallet.address);
    console.log('The contract is deployed:', isDeployed);
    const provider = await client.provider(Address.parse(address));
    const walletContract = client.open(wallet);
    const seqno = await wallet.getSeqno(provider);

    const toAddress = Address.parse(address);
    const transfer = {
      secretKey: key.secretKey,
      messages: [
        internal({
          to: toAddress,
          value: toNano(String(amount)),
          body: 'Congratulations on winning!',
          bounce: false,
        }),
      ],
      seqno: seqno,
      sendMode: SendMode.IGNORE_ERRORS,
    };
    console.log(5);
    const result = await walletContract.sendTransfer(transfer);
    console.log(result);

    let currentSeqno = seqno;
    while (currentSeqno == seqno) {
      console.log('Waiting for confirmation of the transaction...');
      await this.sleep(1500);
      currentSeqno = await walletContract.getSeqno();
    }

    console.log('The transaction is confirmed!');
  }

